# Remove elements from hashset inside hashmap while iterating through java stream

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, hashset

I have a hashmap in Java with a string key and a HashSet value. The hashset may contain many PlacementBundles inside it.

```
public Map<String, Set<PlacementBundle>> placementByConcept;
```

I am trying to remove the value from the HashSet while iterating the map which matches a specific condition.

I tried the below code but cannot remove the matching element from the HashSet.

```
placementByConcept.entrySet()
                  .stream()
                  .map(e -> e.getValue()
                             .removeIf(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")));
```

Comment: `removeIf` is a list function, don't you get any error when applying it on a set?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor `removeIf` comes from `Collection` interface and `Set` extends `Collection`

Comment: Side note: use `Stream.forEach` instead of `map` when your intention is a side effect instead of a mapping to `Steam<Boolean>`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "cannot remove" - do you get some kind of exception or error, or do you just see some unexpected result?

Comment: @Hulk Yeah it wasn't removing the element from the set.

Comment: Any idea how to extract the matching elements instead of removing them from the Set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use forEach:

```
placementByConcept.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().removeIf(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")));
```

Comment: Yes, adding forEach fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Or even simpler `placementByConcept.values().forEach(set -> set.removeIf(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")));`

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why this helps - i.e. the lazy processing of stream pipelines that is only triggered by terminal operations like forEach, but not by intermediate operations like map (In this example here, the stream is eliminated completely).

Comment: Any idea how to extract the matching elements instead of removing them from the Set ?

Comment: @Pp88 

s.getBeatObjectiveId() does not exist since s is an hashSet in my case.

Comment: Sorry my bad try `placementByConcept.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).filter(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Answer (score 1):

<strike>In your case `Set<PlacementBundle>` is an immutable collection. You can't remove an element from it.</strike>

Thank you [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for pointing out the assumption I made which may not be true for the asked question.

If Set is immutable collection and you use foreach as suggested in the accepted answer, you will get `UnsupportedOperationException`

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Slf4j
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Set<PlacementBundle>> placementByConcept = new HashMap<>();
        placementByConcept.put("concept1", Set.of(
                PlacementBundle.builder().beatObjectiveId("scored").build(),
                PlacementBundle.builder().beatObjectiveId("non-scored").build())
        );
        placementByConcept.put("concept2", Set.of(
                PlacementBundle.builder().beatObjectiveId("scored").build(),
                PlacementBundle.builder().beatObjectiveId("non-scored").build())
        );

        log.info("Original: {}", placementByConcept);

        /* This won't give any exception, neither will remove the entries */
        placementByConcept.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .map(e -> e.getValue()
                                     .removeIf(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")));
        log.info("Does not work: {}", placementByConcept);

        /* This will give you the exception UnsupportedOperationException */
        // placementByConcept.entrySet().forEach(e -> e.getValue().removeIf(s -> s.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored")));

        /* This is one of the correct way */
        for (Map.Entry<String, Set<PlacementBundle>> entry : placementByConcept.entrySet()) {
            var filtered = entry.getValue().stream()
                    .filter(placementBundle -> !placementBundle.getBeatObjectiveId().equals("non-scored"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet());
            log.debug("New Value Set: {}", filtered);
            entry.setValue(filtered);
        }

        log.info("After: {}", placementByConcept);
    }

}

@Builder
@Data
class PlacementBundle {
    private String beatObjectiveId;
}
```

Output:

```
Original: {concept2=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored), PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=non-scored)], concept1=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored), PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=non-scored)]}

Does not work: {concept2=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored), PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=non-scored)], concept1=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored), PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=non-scored)]}

After: {concept2=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored)], concept1=[PlacementBundle(beatObjectiveId=scored)]}
```

Comment: How do you know that the OP is using an immutable collection? All I see in the question, is the mentioning of `HashSet`, which is definitely mutable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger). Corrected the wrong assumption.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Remove {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, String>
            map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(1, "Stack");
        map.put(2, "Overflow");
        map.put(3, "StackOverflow");

        int keyToBeRemoved = 2;

        System.out.println("Original HashMap: "
                        + map);

        map.entrySet()
            .removeIf(
                entry -> (keyToBeRemoved == entry.getKey()));

        System.out.println("New HashMap: "
                        + map);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Original HashMap: {1=Stack, 2=Overflow, 3=StackOverflow}
New HashMap: {1=Stack, 3=StackOverflow}
```

Comment: `map.entrySet() .removeIf(entry -> (keyToBeRemoved == entry.getKey()));` is a very convoluted way to do just `map.remove(keyToBeRemoved);` The latter is not only simpler, it will do the job without a linear search through the entire map.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.